# Express with ES6 class 'this' is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, es6-class

Hello I'm trying to create an application using express and es6 classes, but every time the class method is called `this` is undefined.

UserController.js

```
export class UserController {

    constructor() {
        console.log('Class Constructed');
        this.service = new UserService();
    }

    create(req, res, next) {
        console.log('console', this);
        this.service.create(req.body).then((user) => {
            res.send(user);
        });
    }
}
```

route.js

```
import { Router } from 'express';
const router = Router();

router.route('/user/create')
    .post(new UserController().create);
```

I noticed that when I execute `npm run dev`, I got the console in the controller constructor, but when I call the '/user/create' from postman. I got `TypeError: Cannot read property 'service' of undefined`.

Did I miss something? or is this kind of approach possible?

It would be great if someone can help me with this.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you need to `bind` `create` function to class

```
 constructor() {
        console.log('Class Constructed');
        this.service = new UserService();
        this.create = this.create.bind(this);
    }
```

Example

```js
class UserService {
  create(data) {
    return Promise.resolve({})
  }
}

class UserController {

  constructor() {
    console.log('Class Constructed');
    this.service = new UserService();
    this.create = this.create.bind(this);
  }

  create(req, res, next) {
    console.log('console', this);
    this.service.create(req.body).then((user) => {
      res.send(user);
    });
  }
}

function post(callback) {
  callback({
    body: {}
  }, {
    send: () => {}
  }, () => {})
}

post(new UserController().create);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to store the recent created `UserControoller` instance, then call to its `create` function, so `this` is inferred under the scenes.

```
router.route(`/user/create`, (req, res, next) => {
    const controller = new UserController();
    controller.create(req, res, next);
});
```

Or even call the `create` function without storing the instance.

```
router.route(`/user/create`, (req, res, next) => {
    new UserController().create(req, res, next);
});
```

By passing the `create` function without calling yourself, the function will be invoked by `express` at some point and `express` won't be able to bind the `this` property of the `prototype`, since it has no reference to the instance.

Hope it helps.